# Why does my app shutdown overnight?

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, shutdown

I usually do the following at night:

1) Have my app running
2) Press the Home button to go and set the alarm for in the morning
3) Lock the screen on my iPod (4th Gen) at night
...
4) Wake up in the morning before alarm goes off
5) Double-press the Home button to go back to my app (or tap the icon on screen)
6) My app restarts from scratch

Question: Why is my app restarting each time? It doesn't do this unless its left for a long period of time.

I've checked with Instruments and cannot see any continuous memory leaks - it seems stable to me - and - I've had a look with Organizer for any crash logs in Device Logs. There are no crashes for days.

Can somebody please tell me what I should be looking for? I'm running iOS6. Is iOS shutting down my app for some reason? How can I tell? Would there be a method or delegate I can implement within my app to find out - or deny this shutdown?

My app uses about 26Meg of heap memory.

Comment: It's normal. Just make your app restore state when it restarts so users can't tell the difference.

Comment: One would have to ask why you want your app to keep running all night.  For what purpose?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Well I don't really want it to to be honest. I just thought that all apps behaved this way but I guess I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please read carefully following documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Section "Being a Responsible Background App" may answer why your application forced to quit

Comment: @levgenii: Thanks for this.. Is there any way in which you can make iOS 'cleanup' any sooner (just so I can debug/fix this a little easier rather than having to wait overnight for the result)? One of the things that concerns me is that my app takes a while to load its indices - something I have tried to speed up. This is one of the reasons why it would be preferable not to shut down my app.

Comment: If you want to debug loading you can just kill application from XCode, no need to wait overnight. Or you can force quit application on device by double click hardware button and then press "-" on your application